# How to prevent a WebMethod from serializing a json response

Tags: c#, json, serialization, webmethod

I have a web method that returns data.
I have specific code for serializing my object to json in order to ignore nulls and other purposes.

What happens is that .Net serialises the reponse again so:

Object = `{a:2}`

Firsts Serialization = `{"a": "2"}`

Second Serialization = `"{\"a\": \"2\"}"`

How can i prevent .Net from serializing my reponse the second time.

code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object XXX()
{
   return new { a = 2 }.ToJson();
}
```

Comment: If you just return `return new { a = 2 };` what you get?

Answer (score 2):

The `.ToJson()` call is unnecessary - remove it:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object XXX()
{
   return new { a = 2 };
}
```

The reason for this is Web API [serializes to JSON by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_media_type_formatter):

> **What Gets Serialized?**
>
> By default, all public properties and fields are included in the serialized JSON. To omit a property or field, decorate it with the `JsonIgnore` attribute.

So, unless explicitly ignored, or a specific Media Formatter is invoked by the client (via `Content-Type` request header), your return type is serialized to JSON. The double-serialization happened due to the additional `.ToJson()` call.

Your `ScriptMethod` attribute is also unnecessary, as JSON is the default value for [`ScriptMethodAttribute.ResponseFormat` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.responseformat(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: As I stated i have specific serialization code. I want to serialize on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting the serialization method to XML while disabling XML serialization. This will allow you to return a simple string which includes the JSON you serialized yourself.

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public static string XXX() {
        return new { a = 2 }.ToJson();
    }
```